# Eclipse on ubuntu 12.04lts x64 won't run my app in eclipse on a 'real' device

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

Pretty much what the title says. It will run on an AVD but not on my One X. I have android debugging enabled, I have even edit the build.prop and added ro.adb.secure=0 as my One X is running 4.2.2 and apparently that helps disable some of the security settings. Any ideas? My device will come up when auto pick device is ticked but it just shows up as 
Serial number - ????????? AVD name - N/A Target - unknown Debug - (nothing shows here, it's blank) State - ??

Any ideas how to fix this?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have a udev rule configured for your device.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) for details.